# Store array of structs with variable 2D arrays

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Briefly: If you want to test the code, you can find it as Gist on GitHub:
https://gist.github.com/nok/c0ff77db0513384fcbbd

We have a known set of papers. Each paper of type `Paper` has x matrices of type `Matrix`. We want to store an array of papers dynamically and to read these from additional functions. Here is the data structure:

```
typedef struct Matrix {
    int         rows;
    int         cols;
    float**     data;
} Matrix;

typedef struct Page {
    char        id;         // unique id
    int         size;       // size of matrices
    Matrix**    matrices;
} Page;
```

We created required structs with following functions (removed error handling):

```
Matrix *new_matrix(int n_rows, int n_cols, float** data)
{
    Matrix *M = (Matrix *) malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
    M->rows = n_rows;
    M->cols = n_cols;
    M->data = (float **) malloc(M->rows * sizeof(float *));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < M->rows; i++) {
        M->data[i] = data[i];
    }
    return M;
};

Page *new_page(int id, int n_size, Matrix** data)
{
    Page *P = (Page *) malloc(sizeof(Page));
    P->id = id;
    P->size = n_size;
    int i;
    P->matrices = malloc(n_size * sizeof(Matrix));
    for (i = 0; i < n_size; ++i) {
        P->matrices[i] = data[i];
    }
    return P;
};
```

Now, we want to allocate the memory in the separate function `app_init`:

```
Page **pages;       // <--------------

int main(void) {

    app_init();
    app_update();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void app_init() {
    pages = (Page **) malloc(2 * sizeof(Page *));

    Matrix* m1 = new_matrix(3, 5, (float*[5]) {
        (float[5]) { 111, 112, 113, 114, 115 },
        (float[5]) { 121, 122, 123, 124, 125 },
        (float[5]) { 131, 132, 133, 134, 135 },
    });
    Matrix* m2 = new_matrix(3, 4, (float*[4]) {
        (float[4]) { 211, 212, 213, 214 },
        (float[4]) { 221, 222, 223, 224 },
        (float[4]) { 231, 232, 233, 234 },
    });
    pages[0] = (Page *) new_page(1, 2, (Matrix*[2] ) { m1, m2 });

    Matrix* m3 = new_matrix(3, 5, (float*[5]) {
        (float[5]) { 311, 312, 313, 314, 315 },
        (float[5]) { 321, 322, 323, 324, 325 },
        (float[5]) { 331, 332, 333, 334, 335 },
    });
    Matrix* m4 = new_matrix(3, 4, (float*[4]) {
        (float[4]) { 411, 412, 413, 414 },
        (float[4]) { 421, 422, 423, 424 },
        (float[4]) { 431, 432, 433, 434 },
    });
    pages[1] = (Page *) new_page(2, 2, (Matrix*[2] ) { m3, m4 });
}
```

(I guess there is a problem storing all pages in the variable `pages`.)
Then we want see all matrices of all papers:

```
void app_update() {
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<NUMBER_PAGES; i++){
        printf("Page (%d): %d\n", i, pages[i]->id);
        for(j=0; j<pages[i]->size; j++){
            printf("Matrix (%d):\n", j);
            print_matrix(
                    pages[i]->matrices[j]->rows,
                    pages[i]->matrices[j]->cols,
                    (float *)pages[i]->matrices[j]->data[0]);
            printf("\n---\n");
        }
        printf("\n------\n");
    }
}

void print_matrix(int row, int col, float* data) {
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<row; i++){
        for(j=0; j<col; j++){
            printf("%.3f ", data[i*col+j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Reading the values of `pages` works in scope of `app_init()`. But in the scope of `main()` and `app_update()` it fails. How can we store the values permanently?

Comment: a pointer-to-pointer is not the same as an array-of-array. The latter is contiguous in memory while the former isn't (and you seem to be assuming that by writing `data[i*col+j]`.)

Comment: To add to that comment, really you should avoid working with pseudo-2D arrays, they are difficult to use and not very efficient. I really don't know why still so much code uses pointers-to-pointers for that, and in particular why these things are still taught in schools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compound literals in `app_init()` that you pass to `new_matrix()` have automatic storage and will no longer be valid once `app_init()` returns. So the pointers in your `Matrix` types will be pointing to invalid data.

Also, the compound literal you pass to `new_page()` is non-constant, so not really a literal. That is a GCC extension and not part of the C99 language.

Also, your `print_matrix()` function is treating `data` as a pointer to a contiguous block of `rows * cols` `float`s, but your `Matrix` type contains a contiguous block of `rows` pointers to contiguous blocks of `cols` `float`s.

I recommend changing the `data` member of your `Matrix` type and the `data` parameter of `new_matrix()` to be of type `float*`, change the `malloc` to allocate a contiguous block of `M->rows * M->cols` `float`s, and copy `M->rows * M->cols` `float`s from the `data` pointer to `M->data`. You will need to change the compound literals in the calls to `new_matrix()` to be 2-dimensional arrays of `float`. In fact you probably need to make it 1-dimensional to match the parameter of `new_matrix()`, but you can add whitespace to make it appear 2-dimensional.